# Cancel all AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, queue

I have a class which is used to get media file thumbs. This Loader like class starts an `AsyncTask` for every `ImageView` (is called in `SomeAdapter#getView()`). The task itself does a lot of things, and one of them is calling `DiskLruCache`, but when the SD card is unmounted, while the tasks are still running the application crashes.

I know how to register if the card state is changed.

So I need an approach how to stop all the running tasks. Any help would be nice.

Comment: Have a list of your Tasks and when you want to cancel them just iterate through list and call .cancel() on every task

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just iterate through all list & use the following which will cancel all running asynctask.

```
if(myAsyncTask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING))
 {
     myAsyncTask.cancel(true);
 }
```

Comment: I now this topic is very old. That works when you keep track of all AsyncTask, in your example: (myAsyncTask= new class().execute.()... But what about when you start 100 mini asyctask's without keeping any references like  (new class().execute.()...). is no other way to cancel all asynctask referenced whit the same class name?

Answer (score 2):

call cancel() on each of you asynctasks, your asynctasks must check isCancelled() for returning true and if so then return from doInBackground. This is all in AsyncTask documentation.

There is one problem with your solution, AsyncTasks are known to work in parallel on some androids and to work serially on some other. Its actually not a good idea to run them in parallel.  You might consider using ExecutorService as Veaceslav Gaidarji suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `ExecutorService` [look here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

There are nice examples - how to start async tasks, and how to stop them at any time you need.