# Android how to stop/cancel AsyncTask when too many AsyncTask are running?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am working on Real Time message application. I have written the part that handle receiving the incoming message. When I receive a message, I will insert the records in `SQ-LITE` and  trigger the callback to notice the UI for the update(`ListView`). In the callback, I implement a few things to update the UI. I am using cursor adapter. In the callback, I will start an `AsyncTask`, in the background, I will query the database to get the chat history.  In the `onPostExecute`, I will use the cursor that query from the background and assign to the adapter and update the UI.

So my question is:
If there are many incoming messages, it will trigger many `AsyncTask`s and update UI many times. So it will make the `ListView` very "lag" and even user cannot do anything. How can I stop/cancel the `AsyncTask` and only process the latest one since I will get all chat history in database, that means the latest query to the chat history in database should be correct.
Can anyone suggest how to stop the `AsyncTask` or any other ideas to work on this case?

Comment: It looks like you need a queue of `AsyncTask`'s that will manage the number of them... but there's a tiny problem with stopping an `AsyncTask`. See this post for some reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971882/cancel-all-asynctask.

Answer (score 2):

Put your AsyncTasks into a List when creating them (or in the onPreExecute() method), and remove them from the list when they're finished (in the onPostExecute() method). This way your list will contain all the current, not finished AsyncTasks, so when you need to stop all of them, simply iterate through the list and stop every task, except the last added one.

Comment: your idea is great... but how to know which one is running?

Comment: You can check if the task is running easily, the line below is true if the task is running: 
`if (task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)`