# How to check if there is any background task running?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I have an activity in android that is getting data from server using AsyncTask, I'm running the task like the following:

```
new Task.exectue();
```

The problem is there are multiple calls to this AsyncTask and I want to cancel all of them when `onDestroy` or `onBackPressed` called, how can I achieve that? or as another soultion how can I check if there are any background tasks running in activity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971882/cancel-all-asynctask

Comment: @Bubu Are you suggesting I everytime I run a task I add it to a list? Please know that I am not referencing each task call with an object I am always using new task.execute and I don't how many times this task will be called maybe once maybe ten thousand.

Comment: Yes and when you want to cancel them, you iterate through your list, check if the AsyncTask is running and cancel it for each asyncTask. If you have ten thousand asyncTask running in parallel, it's an other problem and you probably have to do your job in a different way :)

Comment: @Bubu haha no I didn't mean there is really ten thousand calls, it's just that the user can click on the same button that calls the task as many as he wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Default `AsyncTask` executes many tasks serially. That means that when the first task finishes it starts the next one and so on. What you can do is

**Global Variable:**

```
private Task myTask;
```

**Method:**

```
public void accessWebService(){
   myTask = new Task().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "Param 1");
}
```

and then in `onDestroy` cancel the Task.

Comment: how can I cancel it in onDestroy when I am using new Task every time without attaching it to an object?

Answer (score 1):

**how can I check if there are any background tasks running in activity?** :

```
   boolean isTaskRunning =  asyncTaskObj.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) ;
```

If you want to cancel that task then use below code :

```
asyncTaskObj.cancel(true);
```

Comment: I know that method but I am not referncing the call with an object, meaning I don't have asyncTaskObj, I am always using new Task.execute()

Answer (score 1):

Have a list of your Tasks and when you want to cancel them just iterate through list and call .cancel() on every task :

```
private ArrayList<Task> mTasks = new ArrayList<>();
```

Each time you want to execute your AsyncTask, add the instance to your list :

```
mTasks.add(new Task.exectue());
```

At the end of your onPostExecute() method of your Task, remove it from your list :

```
@protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
    ...
    mTasks.remove(this);
}
```

Finally in your onDestroy() method, cancel all running AsyncTask :

```
@Override
onDestroy() {
    for(Task task : mTasks) {
        if(task.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)) {
            task.cancel(true);
        }
    }
}
```